# Facebook Invalid Redirect URI for www.domain.com and not domain.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I have a rails app that is on heroku and I have it at a custom .com domain name. I have my facebook app canvas url set to domain.com and when I hit login with facebook it works but when I got to www.domain.com it gives me:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration."
   }
}
```

How would I fixed this in heroku?

Comment: did u find any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Codeglot's didn't quite work for me, but using his elements, this did.

In your application_controller put:

```
before_filter :check_url

#redirecting the herokuapp and www version of domain
def check_url
  url = request.url
  if url.include?('appname.herokuapp.com')
    redirect_to ('http://domain.com')
  elsif url.include?('www.domain.com')
    redirect_to ('http://domain.com')        
  end    
end
```

If you are using bamboo instead of cedar, then replace "herokuapp" with just "heroku"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` to the facebook API or have a redirect in your controller that redirects if you are at `www.domain.com`

```
 before_filter :ensure_domain
 before_filter :get_filter

   def ensure_domain 
    url = request.url
    if url.include?('domain.heroku.com')
        redirect_to url.gsup('domain.heroku.com', 'domain.com')
    eslif url.include?('www.domain.com')
        redirect_to url.gsup('www.domain.com', 'domain.com')        
    end    
   end
```

Make sure the url are getting substituted correctly but that should do it.

Comment: would it be possible to redirect them back to the page they were coming from? lets say a users types in www.domain.com/some-page. How would they automatically go back to domain.com/some-page?

Comment: I tried this in heroku and I get an infinite loop redirect, It seems like it is not substituting

Comment: the redirect was in wrong spot. Fixed. Make sure you test on local.

Answer (score 0):

I would just set up a URL Redirect record on your domain host (GoDaddy, NameCheap, etc.. whoever you bought the domain name through) to redirect all `www.yourapp.com` to `yourapp.com` so this all happens at the DNS server before it even gets to your app server.

Here's a similar question I answered recently dealing with this (that answer is for the opposite case when they wanted all `yourapp.com` requests to redirect to `www.yourapp.com` but its the exact same idea):  [Redirecting subdomain for static assets on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645545/redirecting-subdomain-for-static-assets-on-heroku/6646014#6646014)

By the way, this method will automatically redirect them to whatever path is appended onto the end as well.  So hitting `www.yourapp.com/something` will redirect them to `yourapp.com/something`

Comment: I tried looking into this but godaddy doesnt have something like namecheap has.

Comment: I created the cname but it doesnt cause www.domain.com to redirect to domain.com

Comment: I've not seen many DNS providers that allow you to setup redirects via their DNS control panel - Zergio is one that does allow you to create a redirect record without having to CNAME the domain to your site and then handle the redirect at the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution I could find for heroku that did not lead to infinite redirects or other problems.  Hope it helps.

[Force 'www' in Rails3 hosted on Heroku without .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905664/force-www-in-rails3-hosted-on-heroku-without-htaccess/10679502#10679502)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect keeping current path, you can write like below in application_controller.rb .

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_uri

  def check_uri
    if request.host == "xxx.herokuapp.com" then
      redirect_to request.protocol + "www.xxx.com" + request.fullpath
    end
  end
```