# Force 'www' in Rails3 hosted on Heroku without .htaccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rack

I was wondering if there was a Rack alternative to forcing the 'www' in the URL since Heroku doesn't use .htaccess files.

Maybe even a nice way to do it in routes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals [this Rack middleware](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host), which appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: A quick Google search revealed the new home on GitHub. Link updated.

Answer (score 11):

In your ApplicationController, you can simply create a before filter:

```
before_filter :force_www!

protected

def force_www!
  if Rails.env.production? and request.host[0..3] != "www."
    redirect_to "#{request.protocol}www.#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}", :status => 301
  end
end
```

Or to go the other direction and remove www:

```
before_filter :remove_www!

protected

def remove_www!
  if Rails.env.production? and request.host[0..3] == "www."
    redirect_to "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port[4..-1]}#{request.fullpath}", :status => 301
  end
end
```